# How do I resolve ambiguity in method selection?

Tags: scala

To try out the new value classes in Scala 2.10, I thought I would add a `times` method to Int along the lines of what Ruby offers, making it easy to repeat a code block a few times.  So I wrote this:

```
object Test extends App {
  implicit class Int_times( val n:Int ) extends AnyVal {
    def times( f:    => Any ) { var i = n; while ( i>0 ) { f   ; i -= 1 } }  // A
    def times( f:Int => Any ) { var i = n; while ( i>0 ) { f(i); i -= 1 } }  // B
  }
  3 times   print(1)  ; println                                 // 111 ?
  3 times { print(_) }; println                                 // 321 ?
  var x = 0                ; 3 times { x += 1   }; println(x)   // 3   ?
  var s = new StringBuilder; 3 times { s += 'x' }; println(s)   // xxx ?
}
```

If you are into puzzlers, you might ask yourself at this point what output the above would produce.  It does *not* produce the output I expected (in comments above).

As you can see, there are two methods so that the code to be repeatedly executed can either make use of the index or not.  The output looks good until we get to the StringBuilder test:

```
111
321
3
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
```

I *partially* understand what's going on, but I have some questions.  What I've figured out so far is that while I thought that `3 times { s += 'x' }` would cause version A of `times` to be invoked, version B was in fact invoked.  In fact, if I remove B (and comment out the second test), A is invoked for the last test and works perfectly.

I'm guessing that `{ s += 'x' }` is ambiguous and can be interpreted as either a code block which would satisfy `=> Any` or as an expression whose *result after evaluation* has type `Int => Any`.  That is, `s += 'x'` returns the StringBuilder itself, and StringBuilder has an `apply( ix:Int )` method that allows you to get a particular character.  The compiler makes the latter interpretation and executes the code in the block *once*, before calling `times`, and then passes the result (the StringBuilder itself) to `times`, which then attempts to index into it three times.  Since the StringBuilder only has one character in it at this point, `sb.apply(3)` causes an exception.

So first, can somebody please confirm/correct/elucidate the above?  What are the right terms to use in describing this?

Second, what is an appropriate fix here?  The only thing that occurs to me is to avoid the ambiguity by renaming one of the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, the `apply` method on scala's [Stringbuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder) returns the character at an index.  This gets invoked because `Stringbuilder` can be cast to `f:Int => Any` for instance the following will compile:

```
val s2: (Int => Any) = s += 'x'
```

To get around this the best way I can think of is to explicitly type the anonymous function:

```
3 times { _:Any => s += 'x' };
```

Comment: Thanks, Garrett.  Sounds like there's no way to define the `times` method to eliminate the confusing ambiguity.  I think it would be better to rename or eliminate one of the methods so to avoid confusion.